# Swift setting isdynamic to false after collision

Tags: swift, xcode, dynamic, sprite-kit, collision-detection

Hey guys I have a question.

In my game I want tom let objects (blocks) fall from the sky and then when they hit the ground or another block to freeze/stay in place/don't be dynamic anymore.

I created a function in which I randomly create the block an let them fall from the sky.

```
 func spawnItems() {

    var item = SKSpriteNode()

        item = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "block3");
        item.name = "block";
        item.size = CGSize(width: 90, height: 90)
        item.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 89.8, height: 89.8))

    item.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    item.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    item.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    item.physicsBody?.restitution = 0

    item.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.BLOCK
    item.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.PLAYER | ColliderType.BLOCK | ColliderType.GROUND

    item.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.PLAYER | ColliderType.BLOCK | ColliderType.GROUND

    item.zPosition = 30;
    item.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5);
    item.position.x = CGFloat(getKoordinates());
    item.position.y = 800;

self.scene?.addChild(item)
}


 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(1), target: self, selector: #selector(GameplayScene.spawnItems), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);



}
```

Now I want to set the isDynamic to false, when a block hits the ground/block so it stays in place.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your class is an `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`, you have the scene’s physicsworld `delegate` property set to `self` and then you need to implement the `didBegin(contact:)` method that will be called when 2 sprites, which are set up correctly  (via their `contactTestBitMask` and `categoryBitMask`) make contact.

Comment: yes I tried that. but the problem is, that everytime I set the isdynamic to false when the objects collide, every other item which will be created in the future also got the isdynamic set to false. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Can you post the code for your `didBegin` function by editing the question?